# Merging Google account with Gmail to another Google account without Gmail

Tags: gmail, google, account-management

Let's say a user creates a Google account using `johndoe@example.com`

Soon after, the same user creates a **new** Google account, but instead of using the old email, creates a Gmail address. Now the user has two accounts, one logs in using `johndoe@example.com`, the other is `johndoe@gmail.com`

Since the `@gmail.com` account only has Gmail, and everything else is on the `@example.com` account, is there a way to merge them?

Comment: Whay you want merge? calendar? docs? what?
May be just copy what you want to gmail acoount, and forget about first one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merging accounts](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304) FAQ on Google support site:

> It isn't currently possible to merge separate Google Accounts.
>   However, if you'd like transfer your data from one account to another,
>   this may be done on a per product basis. Or, to start using a new
>   product, you don't have to create another Google Account. Just sign in
>   with your existing Google Account, and visit this list of products to
>   get started.
>
> If you don't have Gmail, you can add it to your account at any time.
>
> If you signed up for Gmail and didn't add it to your existing account,
>   now you have two separate accounts.